I missed Bernina due to strike in Italian railways
Due to strike in Italy we missed Bernina on 16th of June.
Our Bernina trip was on 16th of June, from Tirano (Italy) to Chur (Switzerland). Due to strike in Italian railways,unfortunately we missed our Bernina.
Our plan was taking the train from Milano to Tirano, later on taking the Bernina train from Tirano to Chur. However strike resulted in the cancellation of our first Milano-Tirano connection.
We can prove this mess with documented ticket details if required.
Can we get the refund of Bernina ticket?

If I understand it correctly, you bought the Milano-Tirano and the Tirano-Chur tickets separately?

Yes, they are two separate tickets sold by different companies..

@jcaron if you have any info can u please share with me ,

It's very likely that you simply can't. You didn't show up for the tour, they don't care why. You could ask nicely and maybe they'd be considerate, e.g. give you credit towards a future trip.

@ugoren thanks for reply;)

If you bought a normal ticket you can get it refunded if you can prove that you did not use it. I suggest you contact the place where you bought the ticket from.

Thanks for reply
